# Applying jquery to elements called with infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I have a loop of posts that I use a jquery hover function to expand the elements. My issue is that it only works for elements initially displayed on page load and fails for anything appended with infinite scroll.

This is the script I use to expand a box

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').hover( function() {
       var height = $(this).children('.box-info').height();
       var newHeight = (height + 12);
       $(this).children('.box-image').css('top', -newHeight);
   }, function() {
       $(this).children('.box-image').css('top', 0);
  });
});
```

Then I have a loop and then a script to activate infinite scroll

```
var href = 'first';
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#boxes').infinitescroll({
    navSelector: '.infinitescroll',
    nextSelector: '.infinitescroll a',
    itemSelector: '#boxes .box',
    loadingImg: '<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/images/loading.gif',
    loadingText: 'Loading...',
    donetext: 'No more pages to load.',
    debug: false
}, function(arrayOfNewElems) {
    $('#boxes').masonry('appended', $(arrayOfNewElems));
    if(href != $('.infinitescroll a').attr('href')) {
        href = $('.infinitescroll a').attr('href');
    }
 });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the fiddle provided by you:

The **HOVER** does not work with absolutely positioned elements and animations

Instead of hover you can use the "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events, which do not fire when child elements get in the way:

As per chat see this updated link
http://jsfiddle.net/Gm7Xb/11/

Comment: I tried that before just like it is above and it stopped working for all the elements including the initial loaded. Is there an error in it that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @PolluxKhafra Can you please put the complete code in fiddle .. Are you sure you have correctly replace your code with this code. DO check for javascript error in IE or Firefox.

Comment: I think is correct. Each box has a red box behind that is supposed to be revealed on hover. http://jsfiddle.net/Gm7Xb/

Comment: @PolluxKhafra http://jsfiddle.net/Gm7Xb/5/ In this case i have shown alert that it is working

Comment: Right but notice it doesn't execute making the blue box move up 30px which is the height of the .box-info.

Comment: I am really sorry i dont know how to implement this box visiblity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15117/discussion-between-pollux-khafra-and-ksaini)